# git flow feature finish doesn't push if origin/develop out of sync

Tags: git, git-flow

I just noticed that if we have local and `origin/develop` looking like

```
local:          A---B
origin/develop: A---B
```

If I then do `git flow feature start Z` and work for a while I might end up with:

```
local:          A---B
origin/develop: A---B---C---D
```

I now do `git flow feature finish Z` and I get a warning about:

> Branches 'develop' and 'origin/develop' have diverged.
>   And local branch 'develop' is ahead of 'origin/develop'

I now have (no push):

```
local:          A---B---Z
origin/develop: A---B---C---D---E
```

I try to do `git pull` and down comes a bunch of updates that git merges into `develop`, so I end up with:

```
local:          A---B---Z-----------Z'
                     \--C---D---E--/
origin/develop: A---B---C---D---E
```

If I do a `git push origin/develop` I'm going to muck up our nice neat single `develop` stream, so after some googling I ended up doing:

```
git pull --rebase --prune
git push origin develop
```

This restored me to:

```
local:          A---B---C---D---E---Z
origin/develop: A---B---C---D---E---Z
```

Doing this I actually discovered that a previous feature had also failed because of the same problem... I thought we used `git flow` to hide all these common niggles and pitfalls.

So, am I using `git flow` wrongly? Is there some extra command one should always do before `feature finish` to ensure you don't get out of sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309), you could set locally:

```
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global  rebase.autoStash true
```

That way, any pull on `develop`, done after your `git flow finish`, would effectively rebase `Z` (which is not yet pushed) automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used `git flow` (but we use git flow approach) and basic git commands are enough.

This may not answer your question directly, but I suggest dropping `git flow` extension. You won't have to learn two products: `git` and `git flow`.

Comment: Indeed; I had hoped that `git flow` would try a bit harder to do the right thing, but if it cannot get such a simple case right whilst also misplacing another commit. I previously posted about [another quirk regarding unstaged commits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51494100/1270789) so I suspect my time would have been more profitably spent studying more `git` features.